# NullPointerException on spinner.setAdapter(adapter)

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, spinner

I'm pretty new to programming, so please excuse me for having this simple problem.
My problem is that I'm getting a NullPointerException when trying to run this code, because I can't invoke the setAdapter-method on my spinner.(Spinner seems to be null so that's why :c)
I appreciate every suggestion to solve this problem :)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer=findViewById(R.id.draw_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle= new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        if (savedInstanceState==null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,new TrackingPlanFragment()).commit();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);}

        textInputExercise=findViewById(R.id.text_input_exercise);
        textInputWeight=findViewById(R.id.text_input_weight);
        textInputSets=findViewById(R.id.text_input_sets);
        textInputReps=findViewById(R.id.text_input_reps);

        Spinner spinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.numbers,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fitenss_tracking_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)
```

Comment: Have you verified that the id `spinner1`exists in your layout.xml file ?

Comment: The stack trace would help. It's something that looks kinda like this: `java.lang.NullPointerException: MESSAGE GOES HERE at calculators.IntegerCalculator$.ternCollatz(IntegerCalculator.scala:68) at calculators.IntegerCalculatorTest.$anonfun$testTernCollatz$1(IntegerCalculatorTest.scala:115)` etc.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Spinner.setAdapter(android.widget.SpinnerAdapter)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.fitenss_tracking_app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:61)

Comment: and yes spinner1 exists, but its not in my activity_main.xml but instead in a fragment of the drawer menu in this activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I have finally found the problem.
The problem was, that I didn't put the spinner in the activity_main.xml file but instead in the xml file of a fragment that can be called in this activity.
Now that i've changed that the code works perfectly fine.